# Run Snowflake Task when a data share view is refreshed

Tags: sql, task, pipeline, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake's documentation illustrates to have a TASK run on a scheduled basis when there are inserts/updates/deletions or other DML operations run on a table by creating a STREAM on that specific table.

Is there any way to have a TASK run if a view from a external Snowflake data share is refreshed, i.e. dropped and recreated?

As part of this proposed pipeline, we receive a one-time refresh of a view within a specific time period in a day and the goal would be to start a downstream pipeline that runs at most once during that time period, when the view is refreshed.

For example for the following TASK schedule 
`'USING CRON 0,10,20,30,40,50 8-12 * * MON,WED,FRI America/New York'`, the downstream pipeline should only run once every Monday, Wednesday, and Friday between 8-12.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I can point you to the documentation if you would like to see if this works for the tables you might already have set up:

> Is there any way to have a TASK run if a view from a external
>   Snowflake data share is refreshed, i.e. dropped and recreated?

If you create a stored procedure to monitor the existence of the table, I have not tried that before though, I will see if I can ask an expert.

> Separately, is there any way to guarantee that the task runs at most
>   once on a specific day or other time period?

Yes, you can use CRON to schedule optional parameters with specific days of the week or time: an example:

```
CREATE TASK delete_old_data
WAREHOUSE = deletion_wh
SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 0 0 * * * UTC';
```

Reference: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/tasks.html more specifically: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html#optional-parameters

Comment: For the second part of my question, it wasn't articulated clearly but essentially we receive a one-time refresh of a view within a specific time period and the goal would be to start a downstream pipeline at most once during that time period. For example for the following schedule 'USING CRON 0,10,20,30,40,50 8-12 * * MON,WED,FRI America/New York', the downstream pipeline should only run once in a given day

Answer (score 0):

A `TASK` can only be triggered by a calendar schedule, either directly or indirectly via a predecessor `TASK` being run by a schedule.

Since the tasks are only run on a schedule, they will not run more often than the schedule says.

A `TASK` can't be triggered by a data share change, so you have to monitor it on a calendar schedule.

This limitation is bound to be lifted sometime, but is valid as of Dec, 2019.

Comment: Well it is definitely possible to trigger a TASK based on a change in a table, by setting up a STREAM to capture any DML commands. Are you saying that feature is disabled/not available for data shares?

Comment: How can you do that?  The documentation talks about scheduling a TASK to regularly process a stream, and you have a special TASK WHEN condition that checks the stream, but not the other way around.

Comment: My understanding is that tasks are executed based on some time interval (schedule). They do not automatically get triggered when data has changed

Comment: @SimonD yes, you can trigger a task to run periodically eg. every 10 minutes, or according to a cron schedule every m/h/D/M/W.  A _pipe_ can be triggered by eg S3 events or a REST api call, but any other action must be triggered by database client commands.  Snowflake has no real triggers besides the TASK to my knowledge (yet).